# Except First year Abstract Algebra and commutative Algebra, what else do i need to start read Algebraic Geometry text?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, big-list, book-recommendation

Except First year Abstract Algebra and commutative Algebra text, what else do i need to  read before start read Algebraic Geometry texts?

I am refer to the beginning texts: "Algebraic geometry an Introduction by Perrin", "Basic Algebraic geometry by shafarevich" and "the Royal road to Algebraic geometry".

Please including other beginning Algebraic geometry texts that may be helpful as well.

Comment: You should know basic point set topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Victor May I recommend the classical textbook "*Hartshorne, Robin*: Algebraic Geometry"? Furthermore, I consider indispensable to use a tool like Macaulay2 for the projective algebraic theory, http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/, and  Singular for the local theory, http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/, as well as Pari for the arithmetical theory, http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/